# bash for loop in parallel with n cores

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

I have a `bash` loop that looks like:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $max); do
    my_command $i
done
```

and I would like to run this in parallel on `n` cores. I know that I could do

```
while [[ "$j" -le "$max" ]]; do
    for i in $(seq 1 $ncores); do
        my_command $j &
    done
    wait
done
```

but if `my_command`'s runtime is linear in `$i`, then I am wasting CPU cycles by waiting on the longest running function. How can I continually dispatch new jobs so that `$ncores` jobs are running at any given time? Do I need to run an actual job scheduler like `torque` locally on my machine to accomplish this or can I do this with a simple `bash` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
seq 0 $max | parallel my_command {}
```

Comment: How do I vary $ncores wth this setup?

Comment: -jX where X is the number of jobs to run in parallel. It defaults to the number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

or use xargs:

```
seq 1 $max | xargs -n1 -P$ncores -I% mycommand %
```

To see how it works:

```
seq 1 9 | shuf | xargs -n1 -P3 -I% sh -c 'echo start %; sleep %; echo stop %'
```